# One Cell OR Another

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am working on a formula-  If A3 returns an error #NUM! then use A1 or A2 (whichever one does not have an error message).  I am going to use ISERROR but can not figure out how to tell it to use A1 or A2 (whichever cell does not have an error in it).

Answer (score 1):

You'll need something like

```
=IFERROR(A3,IFERROR(A1,A2))
```

This works for Excel 2007 or later. For earlier versions, you'll have to use `ISERROR` in an `IF` statement:

```
=IF(ISERROR(A3),IF(ISERROR(A1),A2,A1),A3)
```